# How can I get the MAC address of a wireless access point from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mobile

I know there are other posts that dance around this a bit, but I'd like to know how (or if it's even possible) to, using C#, grab the MAC address of the wireless access point that a user is accessing a site or other HTTP-based API from. I work for a hospital and the location of all of our WAPs are known, and would like to move forward with setting up a wayfinding solution that doesn't rely on specific mobile device APIs to determine either MAC addresses or GPS (since I'd like this to work inside buildings as well). I'd also like to not have to use something like Skyhook.

If the MAC address can't be gotten, would assigning specific IP blocks to each WAP, followed by just looking at IPs be a better solution perhaps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the WAP's you have you may be able to use SNMP to get the information.  You'll need to look at what MIB's (Management Information Base) are supported to find the information you are looking for.

Using SharpSNMP API would be a good place to start (http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/).

At this point i have to advise you that MAC addresses are not unique, making the process of using them problematic. Even within a hospital you will find that there are duplicate MAC addresses, making relying on this method of identification at best, inadvisable.

If your wayfinding app is predominantly for use within a building, then relying on WAP positioning will result in a high margin of error. This is caused by relatively long range of up to 150ft. So you can locate them with a margin of error of up to 150ft. Not necessarily what you're after, especially considering all those different levels.

Comment: Thanks! I know I wasn't going to get a high level of accuracy with doing it this way, but was curious about ways to go about it. I'm confident that I could get our network team to change MAC addresses if there are indeed dupes. Hadn't thought of SNMP before - thanks!